# Specify one run/debug configuration for all scripts of a project in PyCharm

Tags: python, configuration, pycharm, console, execution

Is there a way to run all Python scripts within a project using one run/debug configuration in PyCharm? With this configuration, I would like to execute the Python script in the active window in the Python Console without having to select the whole code and clicking "Execute Selection in Python Console".

Many thanks in advance!